# ubuntu 18.04LTS, eclipse photon, Swing app - breakpoints hang entire screen

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I have had the same problem with both Oxygen and Photon latest releases on Ubuntu 18.04LTS with java version "1.8.0_151".

I am debugging a Swing application. After reaching an enabled break-point, the entire Ubuntu GUI "hangs". Mouse clicks on an icon which start other applications and the eclipse window are totally ignored. The only recovery is to reboot the computer.

The strange thing is this appears "intermittently".  It will work fine for long periods of time and the other times it occurs.  It is in one of the "it always occurs" times.
.
I don't recall experiencing this with non-GUI applications.

Any thoughts on how to fix/workaround this?

TIA,
Roy

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I would suggest to check your OS, if it is 32 bit downgrading your eclipse to Oxygen package seems to be the only choice available. Else you can upgrade your OS to 64 bit if supported by processor if you wish to carry forward with Photon package of eclipse. Support by eclipse on 32 bit OS is no longer available.